# Logging data viewed through SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: logging, reporting-services

We would like to log what data a user has seen through reporting services.

Is there any way to automatically save a copy of all reports that the user generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, report snapshots.

Historical versions of the report can be created by creating a snapshot every time the report runs.